# MouldKing set 13132 - Original design, alternate build or cloned MOC?

Tags: sets, clone-brands, moc, set-modification, disney

It seems that Chinese clone brand Mould King will be producing a new set that looks a bit like [LEGO's Disney Castle set (71040)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EbXkgSgKzU).

It has two times as many parts, however, and unlike LEGO's Disney Castle it seems to have a front an back.

Does anyone here know anything about this design?

Is this an original design?

Is this perhaps an alternate build of 2 Disney Castles?

Or is this a clone of some MOC I'm not familiar with?

Here's some pictures of this new set, which I found [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/lepin/comments/dioqz0/mouldking_13132_huge_castle_moc/).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Same look as the original LEGO Disney Castle, but with twice as many parts and with both front and back? Am I the only one feeling they just put two back-to-back?

Comment: @Joubarc : They definitely didn't just put two Disney castles back to back. If you hold a picture of the Disney castle next to it, you do see quite some differences.

Comment: I admittedly didn't try, that was just a random hunch. But yeah, now that I bothered to look at the original LEGO one, it's indeed very different.